# How can I chain up URL redirects and ensure that the user ends up on the first successful one?

Tags: javascript, redirect, settimeout

I want to chain up some redirects but also ensure that the user will go through all of them and stop on the first successful one instead of just skipping to the last one.

My current code:

```
const redirect = () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    window.location = 'https://www.google.com';
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location = 'https://www.example.com';
    }, 1);
  }, 1);
  window.location = 'https://www.bing.com';
};
```

If you try the above code and preserve the network log what you will see is that the first two requests (bing and google) are canceled and only the last one (example) is completed, which is also the URL you will end up to.

What I want is to try all of them in that order and stop on the first successful one.

Comment: You cannot change the website and expect it to still run the "old website" code. When you change the website, the old code is destroyed as a new website is loaded. Still running the old code would be a really big security problem.

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález I thought so too, but how would you do it? If you need to go through some links, how would you do it?

Comment: How about using window.open('https://www.google.com','_blank');?

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Is there a limit of 2 redirects that you can chain up at a time? Should I have intermediate stop points to redirect to the next link each time?

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina It has to be on the same tab.

Comment: @ChristosMaris you can fetch website and see if it's alive. then navigate to it.

Comment: @appleapple assuming the site has CORS. Better try to load their favicon

Comment: @mplungjan I'm not sure fetch favicon would be better, the icon itself can be cors-disabled, and I may not even know it's url.

Comment: @appleapple I also want to use the same logic in deeplinks and from my understanding, it's not possible to fetch those, right?

Comment: @ChristosMaris true, and you cannot even sure the link is there (maybe it's just removed last second). but you can still try to fetch if you already know it's url.